# Validate that string is in proper case using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation

I want to validate a string field to make sure the first letter of each string is in upper case.

For example:

```
"My Name Is Jaas" - This is valid
"My name is Jaas" - Is Invalid because 'name' and 'is' start with lower-case letter.
```

I would like to validate this using regex in C#. What's the correct regular expression for that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were explicit about what a "word" is.  Like, for instance, "where first character of each substring if it is a letter is upper case, and where substrings are separated by whitespace".

Answer (score 3):

So I wouldn't impose this constraint as a 'validation' per say, but would instead do a simple conversion.  Your users will thank you.

Also, while I'm a big fan of regex, this is one case where I think you are better off without it.

You can use the following:

```
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
string formatted = textInfo.ToTitleCase( "yOur STRING hErE" );
```

If you still insist on using the validation you can compare the pre and post formatted values.

PS : You'll need this namespace `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Yep if you can avoid the validation, this is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you do not need any regex here. Use LINQ `.Split().All(p => p.Substring(0, 1) == p.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper())` to check if all words have the first character in upper case (do not forget to add `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq` using statements):

```
var tst = "My Name Is Jaas";
var ntst = "My name is Jaas";
var pass = tst.Split().All(p => p.Substring(0, 1) == p.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper());
var fail = ntst.Split().All(p => p.Substring(0, 1) == p.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper());
```

Output:

```
pass = true
fail = false
```

If you insist on a Regex, you can use the following one:

```
var rxTitleCase = new Regex(@"^(\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s*)+$");
var tstSuccess = rxTitleCase.IsMatch(tst);
var tstFail = rxTitleCase.IsMatch(ntst);
```

Output is the same as above.

Comment: You have my vote for giving the regex string.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the input is always separated by one space, you can split the input on each space and check that the first character of each word is in uppercase with [`char.IsUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
.Split().All(w => char.IsUpper(w[0]));
```

So for example :

```
var correct = "My Name Is Jaas";
var incorrect = "My name is Jaas";

bool willbeTrue = correct.Split().All(w => char.IsUpper(w[0]));
bool willBeFalse = incorrect.Split().All(w => char.IsUpper(w[0]));
```

If it can contain multiple spaces, you can remove the empty entries with this `String.Split` overload:

```
.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All(w => char.IsUpper(w[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This Rexex should work for your request...

```
        var pattern = @"^([\S-[a-z]]\S*\s*)+$";
        var test = "My Name Is Jaas";
        var test2 = "My name is Jaas";
        var test3 = "My Name Is Jaas The 3rd";

        var rx = new Regex(pattern);
        var t1 = rx.IsMatch(test);
        var t2 = rx.IsMatch(test2);
        var t3 = rx.IsMatch(test3);
```

The pattern [\S-[a-z]] means any non-whitespace character except lower case letters.  I did it this way because you say you want Proper Case, and I can not be sure if your substrings might start with non-alphabetic characters.  Your example is simple, but I provide this as a place to start if your actual data turns out to be more complex.

BTW, it is very similar to stribizhev's regex.